# Consolidating changes made in .css with the source .scss files

Tags: css, sass

I have a site where the styles are being compiled into main.css from several scss files. The main.css file was inadvertently modified directly, and now when I recompile and deploy the styles that were made directly to the .css file were obviously missing. I went through to try to reconcile the changes by using text compare on the .css file vs. what SASS generates, but that seems to be a battle that cannot be won. Whenever I make a change in SASS and recompile everything is out of order and I cannot reliably make the changes.

Are there any tools or techniques out there that make this easier? I can hardly imagine this is the first time this has happened.

The first thing I tried was to use a diff between the incorrectly altered CSS and compiled CSS to determine the changes. The problem is that the SASS doesn't appear to be compiled in the same order anymore. When it appears I need to remove styles, the diff changes later in the file and complains those styles are missing.

Comment: Compile again your scss into css. Open a diff tool (you can use git or VSCode) and compare the two files. Than you'll have to manually realize where the added CSS lines belong in the scss files and add them in the respective places.

Comment: I tried doing that but I'm not making any progress. When I try to adjust something in the sass that seems to have been removed, the diff acts like it's out of order.

Comment: This is one of the cases where source version control (SVC) would have been valuable (e.g. git) since it gives you a log of exactly what changed in each file you care about. Without it, diffing files yourself and making best guesses is probably as far as you can go.

Comment: Actually git is not that helpful once one starts adding lines to the compiled css build... It's just not the way to do it. Every programmer with basic experience should know that you simply don't touch build files. You edit the development source only.

Comment: The best suggestion I can give you is to make a long coffee, arm with patience, remove and restructure all the differences into a mess.css or overrides.css file. Than once you're done and your mess.css behaves as expected, slowly port the styles back into old or new. scss files and remove it... :(

Comment: Assuming you have version control setup and these files backed up: Go into your version control system and find the specific edits to the .css file , save these edits somewhere.  Now, remove your .css files (maps included).  Now, re-compile the SCSS files.  Once they output the fresh .css files, go into your SCSS files and add the additions that you saved earlier (the edits that were inadvertently added to the .css file).  Now re-compile your SCSS again and test.

Comment: @skaz... Yep. What I said basically. But a nightmare anyways. Seems like someone not only added styles but also removed, moved, styles in the build... Diffing such complex changes in a huge file is really a pain... Even for super experienced developers. Not to mention order, specificity, unused leftovers, untestable classes, legacy code etc... In a big project there's near 100% chance you'll mess up something, somewhere.

Comment: There's been a few suggestions to use a diff between the altered CSS and compiled CSS to identify the differences. That's the first thing I tried, and the problem with that is that it appears the SASS didn't compile things in the same order. When I found something to remove based on the diff, and I removed it, it would show missing later in the diff. Hard to explain, not really sure why that is. I thought I was getting close but then noticed all the new differences of stuff I thought needed to be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "right" answer here. In my case I just restored the SASS compiled CSS and the designer had to re-make his changes through me back to the SASS styles. I will leave this open in case there are other creative solutions.